# Finding number of solutions to an equation in $\mathbb F_p$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

$p=3 \pmod 4$ is a prime. Let $b\in \mathbb F_p^*$.
Show that the equation $v^2=u^4-4b$ has $p-1$ solutions $(u,v)$ with $u, v \in \mathbb F_p$.

If we write the given equation as $v+u^2=x$ and $v-u^2=-4by$ where $y$ is the inverse of $x$ in $\mathbb F_p^*$ and solve, we get $u^2=-\frac {4b+x^2} {2x}$. So, I need to check when this quantity $-\frac {4b+x^2} {2x}$ will be a perfect square in $\mathbb F_p$. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: what is $F_p$ ?

Comment: @dato, that is prime field: the field of order $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us introduce a "new" variable $w=u^2$. Shiva's idea shows that there are $p-1$ pairs $(v,w)$ such that $v^2=w^2-4b$ - one for each non-zero value of $x$.

The claim follows from the fact that $\gcd(p-1,4)=2$. A consequence of this is that the set of fourth powers in $\mathbb{F}_p$ is exactly the same as the set of squares (the group is cyclic!). Furthermore, both functions $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^4$ are 2-1. This follows either by a counting argument or from the observation that $f$ and $g$ are both endomorphisms of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ with kernel $\{\pm1\}$. So the number of solutions of $v^2=w^2-4b$ equals the number of solutions of $v^2=u^4-4b$, and the former we know to be equal to $p-1$.

---

An alternative way of seeing the same thing (every square is a fourth power) is by Little Fermat. If $w$ is non-zero, then
$$
w^2=w^2\cdot1=w^2\cdot w^{p-1}=w^{p+1}=(w^{(p+1)/4})^4.
$$
Here $p\equiv 3\pmod4$ implies that $(p+1)/4$ is an integer.

Comment: Aah! The set of fourth powers in $F_p$ is exactly the same as the set of squares. Nice. Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: @Jyrki, why we know the number of solutions of $v^2=w^2-4b$ is $p-1$? I am not familiar with diophatine equations, but just simply curious.

Comment: @Easy: That's already in Shiva's work. Write $v+w=x$. Then $v-w=(v^2-w^2)/(v+w)=-4bx^{-1}$. This linear system (in the unknowns $v,w$) has a unique solution. There are $p-1$ possible values for $x$, so...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, right! That's actually simple. Thanks!